# How to sort the relational data?

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data, entity-relationship, nssortdescriptor

Only a little question:

I have an Entity X with an to-many relation to Entity Y

In the viewDidLoad method i fetch all X and sort them by name and ascending and they are displayed in a tableView.

If you choose one of the Xs in the tableView, all relational Y´s are shown in a second tableView.
The result of this fetch also includes all relational Y´s for every X, so i dont have to do an extra fetch for the Y´s - but that leads to my Problem:
The Y´s are in a completly random order (which also changes with every restart of the app) - but i want them sorted by date (<- a attribute in the Y Entity)... how can i do that?

Heres the fetch - code

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Customer" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
}

[self setCustomersArray:mutableFetchResults];
```

and the result looks something like this:

```
Entity X-1
 attribute-x-1
 attribute-x-2
 relation-attribute
  relation-entity-y-1
   attribute-y-1
   attribute-y-2
  relation-entity-y-1
   attribute-y-1
   attribute-y-2
Entity X-2
 attribute-x-1
 attribute-x-2
 relation-attribute
  relation-entity-y-1
   attribute-y-1
   attribute-y-2
```

maybe thats an better example:

```
Customer
 name: Bert
 age: 10
 customerMeasureRealtions
  Measure
   score: 5
   date: 10.10.2010
  Measure
   score: 9
   date: 20.20.2000
Customer
 name: Steve
 age: 20
 customerMeasureRealtions
  Measure
   score: 7
   date: 07.07.2007
```

after the fetch the "Customers" are sorted by "name". But if i access the "Measures" through a "Customer" the order of the "Measures" is random, but i want them sorted by "date".

the code for accessing the Measures ("customer" is a Customer-Entity-Object or Model),
("measuresForCustomer" is the customerMeasureRealtions):

```
- (void)loadMeasureDataForCustomer:(Customer *)customer
{
NSSet *customerSet = customer.measuresForCustomer;
measuresArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[customerSet allObjects]];
[measuresTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: more code please. And what is "dpo"?

Comment: dpo = do ;) i added some information/code

Comment: Ok, can you show us some code how you access the Measures?

Comment: sure, i added it at the end of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two ways you could do this:

1. Initiate a second query to your db and fetch the "measures" for a given Customer. Have a look at [Core data, sorting one-to-many child objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524284/core-data-sorting-one-to-many-child-objects) for this.
2. Transfer the NSSet into an NSArray and sort it in place. An NSSet is always unordered. Have a look at [How to sort a NSArray alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351182/how-to-sort-a-nsarray-alphabetically). Or Apple's documentation: [sortedArrayUsingDescriptors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCJGCJI) in conjunction with a [NSSortDescriptor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/SortDescriptors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000174i).

Comment: great! i used the first approach because i think the sorting by date is easier with core data. thanks a lot XD

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the sort methods of NSSet.

Try:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors
```

Or, if you get your NSArray from your NSSet, you then have a whole host of sorting methods on NSArray to pick from:

```
Sorting
– sortedArrayHint
– sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:
– sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:hint:
– sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
– sortedArrayUsingSelector:
– sortedArrayUsingComparator:
– sortedArrayWithOptions:usingComparator:
```

These come from NSArray and NSSet API documents.